# "Printer-friendly" pages

Tags: 4.7, printing

Does anyone use the little printer icon at the top right of many pages?  It is supposed to produce a printer-friendly view of the page, but the output looks pretty bad.  It shows the main content rather than the whole page that you get from a browser print so is potentially useful.

According to this [this jira](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17133), the printer friendly views were ok in 4.4.20, deteriorated in 4.5.9 and improved a bit by 4.6.9.

So, is this an old piece of cruft that can be removed, or a useful feature in need of attention?

Comment: I tried to use it the other day on a 4.7 install and it wasn't very pretty!  If it is there it should work, perhaps a candidate for moving to an extension.

Answer (score 5):

Agree, it's probably time to remove it.

Over on https://civicrm.org, it's handled like this:

```
.crm-container #printer-friendly {
  display: none;
}
```